# Como obtener todos los registros a partir de un mes especifico en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Hola buenos días comunidad, tengo una duda que no he podido resolver, dentro de una base de datos en SQL Server tengo registros con diferentes fechas que van en un rango de '2018-01-01' hasta '2019-06-10', quiero obtener solo los registros que estén dentro del periodo '2019-01-01', para eso estoy utilizando las siguientes consultas pero no he podido obtener esos registros:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.People WHERE 'FECHA_INICIO' BETWEEN '20190101' AND '20190130';
SELECT * FROM dbo.People WHERE 'FECHA INICIO'>= '20190101' AND 'FECHA_INICIO '< '20190201';
```

Me podrían apoyar a estructurar bien mi consulta, Saludos.

Comment: En principio se ve bien. ¿Puedes compartirnos un ejemplo de los datos que tienes y lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: También agregar la información que estás obteniendo con tus consultas actuales y la descripción de los campos de la tabla People.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si estás trabajando con SQL Server, las columnas no van entre comillas sencillas. Lo que estás haciendo es comparar cadenas de caracteres (strings).

Deberías de mantenerlo así

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.People 
WHERE [FECHA_INICIO] >= '20190101' 
AND [FECHA_INICIO] < '20190201';
```